# Why does jaxb generate code like this?

Tags: java, xml, design-patterns, jaxb

Why does jaxb generate a type parameter named `Result` below ?

Is not cleaner to generate a getter/setter like so :

```
  protected Result result;

         public void setResult(Result value) {
            this.approveRequestResult = (Result value);
        }

        public Result getResult() {
            return result;
        }
```

This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation :

```
 protected JAXBElement<Result> result;

     public void setResult(JAXBElement<Result> value) {
        this.approveRequestResult = ((JAXBElement<Result> ) value);
    }

    public JAXBElement<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }
```

Maybe this a design pattern I am not aware of ?

Comment: Maybe because the result needs to be serializable via JAXB again.

Comment: this isn't a question it is a rant

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - This is an answerable and useful question, see:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19840838/383861

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan no it isn't there is no question here, and if it was corrected, it would still need to be closed as a **duplicate** as you point out.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - There are asking why a field/property of type `JAXBElement` is generated.  There are atleast 3 reasons why this happens.  I've cited a couple of relevant links, but I wouldn't say this is a duplicate of any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAXB will make a field/property of type `JAXBElement` when the value on it's own can not represent the XML representation correctly.  Below are some cases:

1. The element is both nillable and optional.  If the value was simply null which one of these scenarios would it correspond to (see:  [JAXB element that is both optional and nillable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665550/jaxb-element-that-is-both-optional-and-nillable/19666240#19666240)).
2. When representing an `xsd:choice` structure where the property can correspond to different XML elements (i.e. `foo` and `bar`) of the same type (i.e. `xsd:string`).  If the value was `Hello World` would you marshal it as the element `foo` or `bar`.
3. Handlng an element that is nillable and has attributes (see:  [Creating an XML element with xsi:nil and attributes in .Net/Jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797412/creating-an-xml-element-with-xsinil-and-attributes-in-net-jaxb/19798887#19798887))